# Tikzcd: how to get a continuous vertical line?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

In order to illustrate the "Free Functor" w.r.t. a functor `$F$`, I used the following diagram

```
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1cm, row sep=0.8cm]
\mathcal{C}_1 \arrow[rr,leftarrow,"F",dashed]&
\vert\arrow[dd,dash] 
& \mathcal{C}_2\\[-20pt] 
X \arrow[rr,"f",pos=0.3,dashed]
\arrow[rrd,dashed, "j",pos=0.41,swap]&      &  Y\\
\phantom{X}         &   \phantom{X}
&Free(X)\arrow[u, "\hat{f}"']
\end{tikzcd}
\caption{Solution $(X,j,Free(X))$ of the universal
 problem from $\mathcal{C}_1$ to $\mathcal{C}_2$ 
w.r.t.the functor $F$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the vertical line (here done with
`\vert\arrow[dd,dash]`). How to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `start anchor` and `end anchor` keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1cm, row sep=0.8cm]
\mathcal{C}_1 \arrow[rr,leftarrow,"F",dashed]
    \arrow[dd,dash,
    start anchor={[xshift=4ex, yshift=4ex]},
    end anchor={[xshift=4ex]}
    ]&
& \mathcal{C}_2\\[-20pt] 
X \arrow[rr,"f",pos=0.3,dashed]
\arrow[rrd,dashed, "j",pos=0.41,swap]&      &  Y\\
\phantom{x}&& Free(X)\arrow[u, "\hat{f}"']
\end{tikzcd}
\caption{Solution $(X,j,Free(X))$ of the universal
 problem from $\mathcal{C}_1$ to $\mathcal{C}_2$ 
w.r.t.the functor $F$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the result is the following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! in order to get the desired position, I changed [xshift] to [9ex], this is perfect now.

Comment: Nice, the output looks better with the line shifted 9ex

Comment: I will write `\mathrm{Free}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, I adopt this ...